# Communicate to the view without changing object

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on ASP.Net Web Forms application and I need to show a error a message in Aspx page based on a validation check in Data Access layer and application contain two other layers between Data Access layer and Presentation layer they are Business Object and Business Logic.I cant add property to the object which is passing to the Aspx page since need to update so many objects. Is there a way I can show a message by setting flag globally from Data Access layer and access it in Aspx page ? or any other possible way ...?

Comment: In which layer the validation happens? You can throw custom exception proper validation message on validation failure and catch that exception in aspx.cs and display it in the UI

Comment: Validation happens in Data Access layer , cannot throw an exception in this

Comment: Why you can not throw an exception? Ideally the validation should happen at the business logic layer. Setting flag globally won't work as you have many request coming to your application so you can't use a static class or something like that. Other approach would be to return the validation error messages from the business logic/data access layer and use the returned values in the aspx.cs. You can also use an extra `out` parameter in business logic/data access layer methods and you populate that with validation errors. These are approaches you can use but they are not the best practices.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide relevant code. That will help us to understand the issue better.

Comment: I cannot throw an exception since flow should continue without considering  validation result which I have mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

I think best would be adding a field to your data-object, containing the message you want to show. Or throw an exception. But since your question is: Is there something like a global 'flag' you can use: yes there is.

You could use the sessionobject. You can write something to the session like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["someidentifier"] = "Message"
```

In your aspx you can read the session; if it contains a string, you know something went wrong. Don't forget to clear the string after you used is. The session is persistent between postbacks.

This would work, although I don't think it is the best solution architecturally speaking..